# Trouble importing python module despite directory appearing in the path

Tags: python, module, import

I'm trying to import a module into python but having difficulty.

I have defined the Environment Variable PYTHONPATH which contains `C:\MyModules`.

I get the following from Python 2.7 when I ask it about the path.

```
>>> import sys
>>> sys.path
['', 'C:\\MyModules', 'C:\\Python27\\python27.zip', 'C:\\Python27\\DLLs', 'C:\\Python27\\lib', 'C:\\Python27\\lib\\plat-win', 'C:\\Python27\\lib\\lib-tk', 'C:\\Python27', 'C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages']
```

`C:\MyModules` contains the module `foo.pyd`.  I know foo.pyd is a working module because it works on other computers.

When I try to import foo, this happens:

```
>>> import foo
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <fragment>
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

What are the possible reasons this might be happening?

Comment: You're most likely missing some third-party dependencies.

Comment: As in foo.pyd depends on programs that I do not have installed on my computer?

Comment: Run it through: http://www.dependencywalker.com/

Comment: Thanks, this turned out to be the case.  foo.pyd had a third party dependency that was missing.  I've added the third party files and it now loads fine.  My next question is naturally - Why did python tell me the module could not be found?  Why didn't it tell me there was an error loading the module or something more helpful?

Comment: I've submitted it as an answer. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing a dependency, run it through [Dependency Walker](http://dependencywalker.com).

As for your question in the comments. I can only assume the module it was trying to import was written in `C`, which affected Python's backtrace.

*Decided to submit this as an answer*.

Comment: Yes, it was written in C++, good guess!  I am surprised then that Python doesn't complain that its backtrace didn't work correctly, or something along those lines.  It left me wondering why python couldn't find the module.

Comment: Don't confuse the python module with the module that is not found - which is the third party dependency module. foo.pyd is found correctly, but complains when loading that foo.pyd can't find the module it depends on.

Comment: Okay, so `DLL load failed:` was saying that it found the DLL, but loading it failed?  And `The specified module` was the one specified by the DLL, not the one specified by me when I said `import foo`?  That makes more sense.  Thanks.